# writing data to the same file from different functions

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Currently I can write results from within each function to an individual file.

How would I write the results from the 2 functions to the same file?

I think I would need to pull out `writer = pd.ExcelWriter('All Results', engine='xlsxwriter')` with new file name outside of the function but I dont know how to handle the writing of each `df_Final`...

Input:

```
ExcelName='....'
t1=pd.read_excel('.....')
t2=['.......']


def F1(Input_Data):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('F1_Results', engine='xlsxwriter')
    .
    .
    .
    df_Final.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=writeto[3],index=False, header=False)  
    writer.save()
    return
def F2(Input_Data):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('F2_Results', engine='xlsxwriter')
    .
    .
    .
    df_Final.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=writeto[7],index=False, header=False)  
    writer.save()
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
This helper function might help you out:

```
def append_df_to_excel(filename, df, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=None,
                       truncate_sheet=False, 
                       **to_excel_kwargs):
    """
    Append a DataFrame [df] to existing Excel file [filename]
    into [sheet_name] Sheet.
    If [filename] doesn't exist, then this function will create it.

    Parameters:
      filename : File path or existing ExcelWriter
                 (Example: '/path/to/file.xlsx')
      df : dataframe to save to workbook
      sheet_name : Name of sheet which will contain DataFrame.
                   (default: 'Sheet1')
      startrow : upper left cell row to dump data frame.
                 Per default (startrow=None) calculate the last row
                 in the existing DF and write to the next row...
      truncate_sheet : truncate (remove and recreate) [sheet_name]
                       before writing DataFrame to Excel file
      to_excel_kwargs : arguments which will be passed to `DataFrame.to_excel()`
                        [can be dictionary]

    Returns: None

    """
    from openpyxl import load_workbook

    # ignore [engine] parameter if it was passed
    if 'engine' in to_excel_kwargs:
        to_excel_kwargs.pop('engine')

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl')

    # Python 2.x: define [FileNotFoundError] exception if it doesn't exist 
    try:
        FileNotFoundError
    except NameError:
        FileNotFoundError = IOError


    try:
        # try to open an existing workbook
        writer.book = load_workbook(filename)
        
        # get the last row in the existing Excel sheet
        # if it was not specified explicitly
        if startrow is None and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
            startrow = writer.book[sheet_name].max_row

        # truncate sheet
        if truncate_sheet and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
            # index of [sheet_name] sheet
            idx = writer.book.sheetnames.index(sheet_name)
            # remove [sheet_name]
            writer.book.remove(writer.book.worksheets[idx])
            # create an empty sheet [sheet_name] using old index
            writer.book.create_sheet(sheet_name, idx)
        
        # copy existing sheets
        writer.sheets = {ws.title:ws for ws in writer.book.worksheets}
    except FileNotFoundError:
        # file does not exist yet, we will create it
        pass

    if startrow is None:
        startrow = 0

    # write out the new sheet
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, startrow=startrow, **to_excel_kwargs)

    # save the workbook
    writer.save()
```

**NOTE:** for Pandas < 0.21.0, replace `sheet_name` with `sheetname`!

Usage examples:

```
append_df_to_excel('/home/data/test.xlsx', df)

append_df_to_excel('/home/data/test.xlsx', df, header=None, index=False)

append_df_to_excel('/home/data/test.xlsx', df, sheet_name='Sheet2', index=False)

append_df_to_excel('/home/data/test.xlsx', df, sheet_name='Sheet2', index=False, startrow=25)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the function to receive `filename` as a parameter

```
def write_to_excel(filename, input_data):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='xlsxwriter')
    .
    .
    .
    df_Final.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=writeto[3],index=False, header=False)  
    writer.save()
    return

#Then use like
write_to_excel("F2_Results", input_data)
```

Comment: The problem with this code is that it only writes the results of the last function to file...